# Is there a property that is set by the field API once fields have been attached to an entity?

Tags: entities

Is there a property that is set by the field API once fields have been attached to an entity?

For example

```
$entity->fields_attached = TRUE
```

I have been unable to find any information on this, I am looking for a quick and easy way to know if fields have been attached to my own custom entities. If field API does not do something like I have suggested in the question I will handle it myself but I wanted to double check with you fine folks...

If not, I will make a suggestion for this for the Entity API in contrib whenever it attaches fields.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Can't see](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) anything like that going on. You could test a known field, if this is a specific question and you know to expect certain field, but obv. this no help if your question is more about the general case.

Comment: Cheers for the answer :) You're right, I could certainly test for a specific field but I'm not sure I want to have to. I think a more generic solution would be easier. Am I suggesting something particularly crazy here?

Comment: no, sounds sensible to me (have the issue all the time with `$user` which is field-less, where as $account = user_load($user->uid) is not)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no property on the entity, but you can use [field_info_instances()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) to check on which bundles the field is in use.